# JQuery list select next <a> and add class

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am trying to use a next image link to select the next  tag in a list of elements and add a class to the element when it is clicked. I would also like to remove the class from the previous  tag aswell. I have tried using the .next('a') selector and also the .nextAll('a:first'), but cannot seem to get it to work at all. I have also tried to select the next 'NavigationItem'.

My code is as follows:

```
        <div id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="navSelected NavigationItem" href="#" >Section 1</a><span>ben</span></li>
                <li><a class="NavigationItem" href="#" >Section 2</a><span>ben</span></li>
                <li><a class="NavigationItem" href="#" >Section 3</a><span>ben</span></li>
                <li><a class="NavigationItem" href="#" >Section 4</a><span>ben</span></li>
                <li><a class="NavigationItem" href="#" >Section 5</a><span>ben</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

  <img class="prev" src="img/prev.gif" alt="prev" width="42" height="53" />
  <img class="next" src="img/next.gif" alt="next" width="42" height="53" />
```

and the jQuery:

```
        $('.next').click(function(){
                $('a.navSelected').nextAll('a:first').addClass('navSelected');
                $('.NavigationItem').removeClass('navSelected');

        });
```

I am also trying to do the reverse for the previous button, but cant seem to get that working either.

Thanks for your time, any help would be greatly apprecitated.

Simon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.next').click(function() {
    $('#navigation li a.navSelected').removeClass('navSelected')
        .parent().next().find('a.NavigationItem').addClass('navSelected');
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/UQwn9/1/

Or if you need to swich to first on the last element:

```
$('.next').click(function() {
    var $el = $('#navigation li a.navSelected').removeClass('navSelected');
    var $next = $el.parent().next();

    if ($next.length == 0)
        $next = $('#navigation li:first');

    $next.find('a.NavigationItem').addClass('navSelected');
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/UQwn9/2/

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your answer, and thanks for the switch as well! I have managed to reverse it for the prev button as well. Legend. Thanks for making me aware of the parent method as well, I'm still learning jQuery and have a long way to go!

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `next('a')` coz your current object is inside `<li>` it's a difference of one level, so just change this line to:

```
 $('a.navSelected').parent().next('li').find('a').addClass('navSelected');
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments, and thanks for making me aware of why I wasn't selecting the current object.